# javax.faces.FacesException , java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, aplicação-web

O seguinte erro(descrição completa abaixo):

> com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute WARNING: #{testeHibernate.save}: java.lang.NullPointerException javax.faces.FacesException: #{testeHibernate.save}

Esta a acontecer quando eu carrego no botão registar ou seja não me deixa inserir na base de dados.

Classes

UtilizadorDAO.java

```
package DAO;

import Classhiber.Utilizador;
import java.util.List;

public interface UtilizadorDAO {
    public void addutilizador (Utilizador ut);
    public List<Utilizador> findallutilizador();

}
```

UtilizadorDaoimpl.java

```
package Impl;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import Classhiber.Utilizador;
import DAO.UtilizadorDAO;

public class UtilizadorDAOimpl implements UtilizadorDAO {
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public void addutilizador(Utilizador ut) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.persist(ut);
        tx.commit();
        session.close();    }

    public List<Utilizador> findallutilizador() {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
        List<Utilizador> Utilizadorlist = session.createQuery("from Utilizador").list();
        session.close();        
        return Utilizadorlist;
    }


}
```

testeHibernate.java

```
 import java.util.List;

    import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
    import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
    import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
    import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
    import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
    import Classhiber.Utilizador;
    import DAO.UtilizadorDAO;
    import Impl.UtilizadorDAOimpl;
    @ManagedBean
    @SessionScoped
    public class TesteHibernate {

        public UtilizadorDAO utdao;

        private Utilizador utiliza;

        public TesteHibernate()
        {
             utdao = new UtilizadorDAOimpl();
             utiliza = new Utilizador();    
        }

        public UtilizadorDAO getUtilizadorDAO() {
            return utdao;
        }

        public void setUtiliza(UtilizadorDAOimpl ut) {
            this.utdao = ut;
        }

        public Utilizador getUtiliza() {
            return utiliza;
        }

        public void setUtiliza(Utilizador utz) {
            this.utiliza = utz;
        }

        public void save() {
            // Calling Business Service
            utiliza.setIdUt(12);
            System.out.println(utiliza.getUser());
            System.out.println(utiliza.getPass());
            System.out.println(utiliza.getTip());

            utdao.addutilizador(utiliza);
        }
        }
```

Spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/xp" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>


<!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
<bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>Classhiber.Utilizador</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="UtilizadorDAOimpl" class="Impl.UtilizadorDAOimpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

index.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <script name="jquery/jquery.js" library="primefaces"></script>
    <title>Register Utilizador</title>
</h:head>
<h:form>
    <p:growl id="messages"></p:growl>
    <p:panelGrid columns="2">
        <p:outputLabel value="Enter Utilizdor User:"></p:outputLabel>
        <p:inputText value="#{testeHibernate.utiliza.user}"></p:inputText>
        <p:outputLabel value="Enter Utilizador Pass:"></p:outputLabel>
        <p:inputText value="#{testeHibernate.utiliza.pass}"></p:inputText>
        <p:outputLabel value="Enter Utilizador tip"></p:outputLabel>
        <p:inputText value="#{testeHibernate.utiliza.tip}"></p:inputText>                     
    </p:panelGrid>
    <p:commandButton value="Register" action="#{testeHibernate.save}" ></p:commandButton>
</h:form>
</html>
```

Erro

```
 com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute
WARNING: #{testeHibernate.save}: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.faces.FacesException: #{testeHibernate.save}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Impl.UtilizadorDAOimpl.addutilizador(UtilizadorDAOimpl.java:29)
    at TesteHibernate.save(TesteHibernate.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:273)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 27 more

1
3
Ago 29, 2015 8:07:19 PM com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl handlePartialResponseError
SEVERE: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Impl.UtilizadorDAOimpl.addutilizador(UtilizadorDAOimpl.java:29)
    at TesteHibernate.save(TesteHibernate.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:273)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 27 more
```

Obrigado. (Desculpem se tem algum erro de programação grave mas tou a aprender)

Comment: Ja meti essas parte do codigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na sua classe `testeHibernate.java`:

`public UtilizadorDAO utdao;`
Não é instanciado (portanto está nulo) e está sendo usado no método `save()`:
Por isso o erro:

> {testeHibernate.save}: java.lang.NullPointerException

```
public void save() {
    // Calling Business Service
    utiliza.setIdUt(12);
    System.out.println(utiliza.getUser());
    System.out.println(utiliza.getPass());
    System.out.println(utiliza.getTip());
    utdao.addutilizador(utiliza);
}
```

Tem duas formas de corrigir isso, uma delas é instanciar `utdao` ao declará-la (igual fizeste com `utiliza`)

```
public class testeHibernate {
    public UtilizadorDAO utdao = new UtilizadorDAO();
    private Utilizador utiliza = new Utilizador();
    ...
}
```

ou criar um construtor para instanciar todas as variáveis que serão usadas (recomendo usar esta).

Um construtor deve ser `public`, sem nenhum tipo de retorno e deve ter o mesmo nome da classe. Um construtor para a sua classe ficaria algo como:

```
public TesteHibernate(){
  utdao = new UtilizadorDAO();
  utiliza = new Utilizador();
}
```

Ainda há outra maneira, que é instanciar no próprio método `save()`

```
public class testeHibernate {
    public UtilizadorDAO utdao = new UtilizadorDAO();
    private Utilizador utiliza = new Utilizador();
    ...
}
```

porém isso não recomendável, afinal você teria que instanciar a variável em todos os métodos que fosse usa-lá.

Answer (score 1):

```
 #{testeHibernate.save}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Dentro do método save você está utilizando as variáveis `utiliza` e a `utDAO`

Você inicializou a variável `uitiliza` mas não inicializou a `utDAO`.

Minha sugestão é criar um **construtor** para a classe `TesteHibernate` para **inicializar as variáveis** que precisar.

**OBS:** No outro tópico eu sugeri colocar a primeira letra da classe maiúscula. Vejo que ainda está minúscula.

**Código do construtor:**

```
public TesteHibernate(){
  utdao = new UtilizadorDAO();
  utiliza = new Utilizador();
}
```

O nome do construtor precisa ser o mesmo nome da classe. Coloquei `TesteHibernate` maiúsculo supondo que você irá alterar o nome da classe colocando o `TesteHibernate` maiúsculo também.

Quando colocar dentro do construtor `utiliza = new Utilizador();` você pode alterar onde está a declaração da variável e deixar apenas `Utilizador utiliza;`